# How to add extension to apigee-emulator on local environment?

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce, apigee, google-cloud-code

Recently we get the need for work on the same apigee proxy more than one developer. So we are trying to use the `apigee-emulator` to allow us to use git as version control

We already have everything setup for VScode as it says on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/local-development/setup).

The problem is with an `extension callout we have inside one of our proxies that we need to access to salesforce. When we try to push our proxies to the apigee-emulator we get this error

[image]

If we search for the callout we can see it's the one that try to access to salesforce

[image]

How can we add this extension to be used inside the apigee-emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error it looks like you are using Apigee Edge ExtensionCallout policy.

The vscode extension and the emulator cater towards the features available in the X and hybrid versions of Apigee. More information [here](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Apigee/VS-code-plugin-and-emulator-for-Apigee-Edge/m-p/169306/highlight/true#M67436)

The extensions feature you are using has been replaced by the [Integration callout](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/reference/policies/integration-callout-policy) policy.

Hope that helps